# How to code for a UIButton in a Storyboard scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I don't know why but after searching on Google and here, no one seems to have this problem.

I have added a new storyboard scene right next to my main scene, and wrote a code for a button which will trigger a partial curl transition to the new scene.

On my new scene, are a controls, here's my problem. How can I code for them? I cannot add them as IBOutlet or IBAction to my main scene's view controller which is pretty obvious. So what should I do? How can I add a new ViewController.h/m file for that new scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add this method to your ViewController.h/m, you will need to set the class of this view controller to "ViewController". To do this, selected the view, and select "Show the identity inspector" in inspector, and then type the view controller class (ViewController) in Class field.

If you want this view controller to be in a different class, create that class without an XIB file and type that class name in Class field.

This will allow you to declare the IBAction/IBOutlet to that button in the class you specify.

Comment: I realized about five minutes after I asked the question. But thank you anyway!